# Can't use Express.js in my React JS Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, polyfills

I'm trying to implement express.js into my react js Project, but when I add those two lines to my app.js code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()"
```

I am facing the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js 19:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\body-parser\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js 201:12-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js 21:15-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\content-disposition'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\cookie-signature'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 15:17-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 16:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 17:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\etag'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 21:12-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 22:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 29:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 17:11-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 19:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 20:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 23:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 23:18-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 16:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 17:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js 15:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\mime-types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 1:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\mime'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 2:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/parseurl/index.js 14:10-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\parseurl'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 22:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 27:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 30:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js 18:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\serve-static'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js 20:10-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '[myReactProject]\node_modules\serve-static'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
```

**How to recreate this Problem:**

- start by creating a new react project via the "create-react-app" command
- install express using npm/yarn
- add "const express = require('express')" and "const app = express()" to app.js

**What I've already tried:**

- included polyfills via (for Example): resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false } for every dependency listed in the error
- installing every dependency seperatly

Comment: You are trying to use server side package, in front end package. `express` is a package that uses NODEJS ONLY packages. So of course it does not work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to separate the frontend form the backend. That is, in your project directory, try to create two different folders, one titled `Frontend` and the other titled `Backend`.

Then, create an `index.js` file inside the backend folder and install `express` there!

This way, you can import the express and use it inside the backend and run it on a different server port.

### Links That May Help!

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/

https://rapidapi.com/blog/create-react-app-express/

Answer (score -1):

You must have 2 different folders for Frontend and Backed and you must have 2 different ports. one for Frontend and one for Backend.

React isn't used on the server side.

example :

frontend
-app.js listening on port localhost://3000
backend
-app.js listening on port localhost://3000